Copper acetate solution turned brown
I just made a solution with 50mL of 20% vinegar and 50mL of 3% hydrogen peroxide, then I put in 5g of copper wires. It started turning blue, however, after like 2 hours, it turned completely brown, almost black. Can someone help me with this??

It may be copper peroxide.

Or cupric oxide

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144804/electrolysis-of-copper-chloride-in-solution-of-vinegar-h2o2-nacl-after-coppe
